# Declaring a decimal(9,6) field in sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to generate a model in Ruby on rails project using sqlite3.
I need to declare 2 fields in my Business Entity for location point here is my command:

```
rails g model Business name:string category_id:integer lat:decimal(9,6) long:decimal(9,6)
```

But I keep getting this syntax error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Im using: Rails 4.0.0
Ruby: 2.0
database: sqlite3

Can anyone help me to solve this?!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try either `{1.2}` or `{1-2}`, as pointed out here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4602

```
rails g model Business name:string category_id:integer lat:decimal{9.6} long:decimal{9.6}
```

which generates:

```
class CreateBusinesses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :businesses do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :category_id
      t.decimal :lat, :precision => 9, :scale => 6
      t.decimal :long, :precision => 9, :scale => 6

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```